Vue - v-if not updating with onMounted
I'm simply trying to make a div only appear once a variable changes from false to true and I'm telling it to change the value once the component is mounted. However the v-if which is supposed to be looking for that change is not working to create the div.
<script setup>
  import { onMounted } from 'vue'

  let onceMounted = false
  
  onMounted(() => {
    onceMounted = true
    console.log(onceMounted)
  });

<div>
  Hello
  <div v-if="onceMounted === true">
    World
  </div>
</div>

The console log confirms it changing fine, just the v-if isn't updating. I've checked using v-show after checking out other questions on here like this one. I'm guessing there's something I'm just missing?

The difference in what you linked is that they didn't use onMounted. If you remove the onMounted part and just assign a bool straight away you can see the "World" showing/hiding. But you are mutating the value later and in order to see the changes in the your template you need reactivity. You can use ref for this. docs

onceMounted is not reactive. Does this v-if serve a real purpose?

It's simply there because the data needed to be displayed in this div is not available instantly but is by the time the app is mounted. So it just made sense to keep things simple (to me anyway) to just change a false to true when mounted and trigger the div and look for the data needed.

@Chobbit I see. Notice if data fetching is async, it won't be available on mount. Any way, the approach would be the same, and it's solved by making a value reactive, as the answer shows. Or use suspense as the alternative

onceMounted should be reactive using ref, then use .value to mutate it :
<script setup>
  import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

  const onceMounted = ref(false)
  
  onMounted(() => {
    onceMounted.value = true
    console.log(onceMounted.value)
  });
</script>
<div>
  Hello
  <div v-if="onceMounted"><!-- no need for .value in template -->
    World
  </div>
</div>


This was exactly what I needed, I had seen other questions with answers that mentioned using ref but for slightly different reasons, and I did try something similar but the bit I was missing was the .value part that was stopping it from working. Thank you that was a clear reply and really helped figure out that last missing part.

You forget to set the onceMounted = true;
Before:
onMounted(() => {
    onceMounted = false
    console.log(onceMounted)
  });

After:
onMounted(() => {
    onceMounted = true
    console.log(onceMounted)
  });


I apologise that was a mistake in my original post but not my local code that isn't working, I've updated it to = true above to reflect my original code. However this doesn't fix the issue for me still.
